# What is the Adjoint of inverse of a matrix?

Tags: matrices, inverse, adjoint-operators

I recently read that when we take the Adjoint of the inverse of a matrix we get the matrix itself i.e. $\operatorname{adj}(A^{-1})=A$
I am unable to prove the result.
Help!

Answer (score 6):

It is not true, I'm afraid.

If the matrix $A$ is invertible, then
$$
A^{-1}=\frac{1}{\det A}\operatorname{Adj}(A)
$$
and, in general, the relation
$$
(\det A)I = \operatorname{Adj}(A)A
$$
holds for all matrices. In particular, for $A^{-1}$ in place of $A$,
$$
(\det(A^{-1}))I = \operatorname{Adj}(A^{-1})A^{-1}
$$
so that
$$
\operatorname{Adj}(A^{-1})=(\det A)^{-1}A
$$

Thus we have $\operatorname{Adj}(A^{-1})=A$ if and only if $\det A=1$.

For instance, if
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4 \end{bmatrix}
$$
then
$$
A^{-1}=
\begin{bmatrix} -2 & 1 \\ 3/2 & -1/2 \end{bmatrix}
$$
so that
$$
\operatorname{Adj}(A^{-1})=
\begin{bmatrix}
-1/2 & -1 \\
-3/2 & -2
\end{bmatrix}=
\frac{1}{-2}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4 \end{bmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 0):

This is not true, since

$\operatorname{adj}(A^{-1})= (\operatorname{adj}(A))^{-1}$

This can be proved by proving that both LHS and RHS equals to the same expression i.e $ \frac{A}{|A|} $

Proof:

Let $A^{-1} = B$

$\operatorname{adj}(A^{-1}) = \operatorname{adj}(B)$

Now we know

$\operatorname{adj}(B) = B^{-1}|B|$

Replacing B by A inverse we get:

$B^{-1}|B| = (inv(A))^{-1}|A^{-1}|$

Which equals:
$ \frac{A}{|A|} $   as

$ |A^{-1}| = \frac{1}{|A|},  (inv(A))^{-1} = A $

Now we will prove

$ (\operatorname{adj}(A))^{-1} = \frac{A}{|A|}$

We know:
$(\operatorname{adj}(A))^{-1} = (A^{-1}|A|)^{-1} $

By reversal law:

$ (A^{-1}|A|)^{-1} = (|A|)^{-1}A $

$ (|A|)^{-1}A = \frac{A}{|A|} $

Hence both RHS and LHS equals
$ \frac{A}{|A|} $